# RuntimeError 'CUDA error' when trying the Google Cloud AI Platform Tutorial for PyTorch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch

I've been trying to get started with Google Cloud's AI Platform. I have been following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/getting-started-pytorch#gpu_1

My own models are written in PyTorch, hence the choice to get started with PyTorch. Why I want to use the GPU I guess goes without saying.

I've tried to follow the instructions to the letter, and I've used the provided sample code. Yet I still run into errors. I can create a job without problems, but the job ends up failing with the following error:

`RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device`

I'm relatively new to PyTorch and completely new to GCP, so I have no idea how I would go about fixing this and any help would be much appreciated.

Full trace:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 123, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 119, in main
    experiment.run(args)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/experiment.py", line 132, in run
    train(sequential_model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/experiment.py", line 37, in train
    for batch_index, data in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 347, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 387, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 74, in default_collate
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 74, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 55, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

Comment: Are you using Colab or literally GCP where you are installing things ontop of a linux container, etc? A few things to make sure you have: (1) CUDNN from Nvidia, and (2) an environment that specifies the cudatoolkit matching the CUDNN version like so: `conda create -n my_ml python=3.7 pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`

Comment: I'm using a the pre-built container provided by GCP as described in the linked tutorial.

Comment: Which container, the one with Pytorch version 1.4 or 1.6? It seems like Pytorch 1.4 is having [issues with multiples GPU cards](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/31285). You could also use a custom container and [build Pytorch from source](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#linux-from-source).

Comment: The one with Pytorch version 1.6: `gcr.io/cloud-ml-public/training/pytorch-gpu.1-6`

Comment: I guess it must indeed have something with the GPU variant; I've tried running the tutorial for CPU-only training and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to reproduce the same issue with `pytorch-gpu.1-6`.
As a workaround, it works with the `pytorch-gpu.1-4`

I suppose that something in the code changed from 1.6 but not sure what as I am not familiar with Pytorch.

Besides, up to version 1.7, it seems that the code to [select the device](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#use-nn-parallel-distributeddataparallel-instead-of-multiprocessing-or-nn-dataparallel) hasn’t changed compared to our [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/7dd7b56704a4e6348db05fe8bbf415f201f81228/training/pytorch/structured/python_package/trainer/experiment.py#L112).

Additionally, [our GPU basic tier Nvidia Tesla K80](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/machine-types#scale_tiers) seems to be [supported by CUDA 9.0, 9.2, 10.0 OR 11](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-tesla-k80-cuda-version-support/67676)

In any case, I have created a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180604520) on issuetracker so the AI Platform engineering team can investigate it.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to work around it myself by using a custom container and using the latest versions of everything, which was some effort but I eventually got to work.